# Error while deploying Ruby Application into Stackato

Tags: ruby, deployment, bundler, stackato

I am  deploying **Rack based ruby Application in stackato**.  Because of local network i have downloaded all my gems locally when i try to push after some stagging i am getting the following error.

```
 Fetching missing gems from RubyGems
 staging: http://production.s3.rubygems.org/gems/bundler-1.2.1.gem:
 staging: 2013-12-13 01:36:21 ERROR 504: Host production.s3.rubygems.org lookup 
 failed: Host not found.
 staging: wget failed to fetch http://production.s3.rubygems.org/gems/bundler-1.2.1.gem
  staging: /home/stackato/stackato/vcap/staging/lib/vcap/staging/plug/gemfile_task.rb:134:in `block in install_gems': Failed fetching missing gems from RubyGems (RuntimeError)
Failed to stage application:
 staging plugin exited with non-zero exit code
```

i thought it is a Gateway error but when i go through my gem list i found

```
bundler (1.2.1)
```

if i run bundle install --local --deployment and bundle package it is successfully running the bundle. i have an rbenv here rather than rvm i tried to install bundler at global.

I don't know why it is hitting that host.

Killing my time since three days.

Help me please Thanks in advance

**Update**

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gemserver.portal.sb.net'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'grape','0.6.0'
gem 'rack-fiber_pool'
gem 'haml'
gem 'hashie'
gem 'idp-utilities', require: %w(idp/test_utils/string idp/middleware/idp_url        idp/logging)
gem 'idp-clients', '~> 0.1.8', require: %W(idp/middleware/clients idp/content/client idp/user/client idp/session/client idp/authentication/client idp/exceptions idp/user/exceptions)
gem "newrelic_rpm", "~> 3.6.8.168"

group :test do
  gem 'page_object'
  gem 'cucumber', '1.2.5'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'watir-webdriver'
  gem 'childprocess'
  gem 'waitforit'
  gem 'httparty'
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'mirage', '3.0.0.alpha.15', require: 'mirage/client'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'idp-user_service_mocks'
  gem 'idp-content_service_mock'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rake'
  gem 'shotgun'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'sinatra-contrib'
  gem 'sinatra-reloader'
end
```

and my Gemfile.lock is

```
GEM
remote: http://rubygems.org/
remote: http://gemserver.portal.sb.net/
specs:
  activesupport (4.0.1)
   i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
   minitest (~> 4.2)
   multi_json (~> 1.3)
   thread_safe (~> 0.1)
   tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
addressable (2.3.5)
akami (1.2.0)
  gyoku (>= 0.4.0)
  nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
atomic (1.1.14)
axiom-types (0.0.5)
  descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
  ice_nine (~> 0.9)
backports (3.3.5)
builder (3.2.2)
childprocess (0.3.9)
  ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
coercible (0.2.0)
  backports (~> 3.0, >= 3.1.0)
  descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
cookiejar (0.3.0)
cucumber (1.2.5)
  builder (>= 2.1.2)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
  gherkin (~> 2.11.7)
  multi_json (~> 1.3)
daemons (1.1.9)
descendants_tracker (0.0.3)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
em-http-request (1.1.1)
  addressable (>= 2.3.4)
  cookiejar
  em-socksify (>= 0.3)
  eventmachine (>= 1.0.3)
  http_parser.rb (>= 0.6.0.beta.2)
em-socksify (0.3.0)
  eventmachine (>= 1.0.0.beta.4)
em-synchrony (1.0.3)
  eventmachine (>= 1.0.0.beta.1)
equalizer (0.0.7)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
faraday (0.8.8)
  multipart-post (~> 1.2.0)
faraday_middleware (0.9.0)
  faraday (>= 0.7.4, < 0.9)
ffi (1.9.3)
gherkin (2.11.8)
  multi_json (~> 1.3)
grape (0.6.0)
  activesupport
  builder
  hashie (>= 1.2.0)
  multi_json (>= 1.3.2)
  multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
  rack (>= 1.3.0)
  rack-accept
  rack-mount
  virtus
gyoku (1.0.0)
  builder (>= 2.1.2)
haml (4.0.4)
  tilt
hashie (2.0.5)
hike (1.2.3)
http_parser.rb (0.6.0.beta.2)
httparty (0.12.0)
  json (~> 1.8)
  multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
httpi (2.0.2)
  rack
i18n (0.6.5)
ice_nine (0.10.0)
idp-clients (0.1.8.455)
  activesupport
  em-http-request
  em-synchrony
  faraday
  faraday_middleware
  savon (= 2.2.0)
idp-content_service_mock (0.0.1.495)
  mirage (>= 3.0.0.alpha.10)
idp-user_service_mocks (0.1.3.460)
  em-synchrony
  eventmachine
idp-utilities (3.1.1.269)
  childprocess
  grape
  net-ssh-gateway
  sprockets
  waitforit
  watir-webdriver
json (1.8.1)
mini_portile (0.5.2)
minitest (4.7.5)
mirage (3.0.0.alpha.15)
  childprocess
  haml
  hashie
  httparty
  ptools
  sinatra
  thor
  waitforit
multi_json (1.8.2)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
net-ssh (2.7.0)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
  net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
newrelic_rpm (3.6.8.168)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
  mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
nori (2.1.0)
page_object (2.2.0.15)
  watir-webdriver
  watir-webdriver
ptools (1.2.2)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-accept (0.4.5)
  rack (>= 0.4)
rack-fiber_pool (0.9.3)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
  rack (>= 1.0.0)
rack-protection (1.5.1)
  rack
rack-test (0.6.2)
  rack (>= 1.0)
rake (10.0.4)
rspec (2.13.0)
  rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
rubyzip (1.0.0)
savon (2.2.0)
  akami (~> 1.2.0)
  builder (>= 2.1.2)
  gyoku (~> 1.0.0)
  httpi (~> 2.0.2)
  nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
  nori (~> 2.1.0)
  wasabi (~> 3.1.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.37.0)
  childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rubyzip (~> 1.0.0)
  websocket (~> 1.0.4)
shotgun (0.9)
  rack (>= 1.0)
simplecov (0.7.1)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  simplecov-html (~> 0.7.1)
simplecov-html (0.7.1)
sinatra (1.4.4)
  rack (~> 1.4)
  rack-protection (~> 1.4)
  tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
sinatra-contrib (1.4.0)
  backports (>= 2.0)
  eventmachine
  rack-protection
  rack-test
  sinatra (~> 1.4.2)
  tilt (~> 1.3)
sinatra-reloader (1.0)
  sinatra-contrib
sprockets (2.10.0)
  hike (~> 1.2)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
thin (1.5.1)
  daemons (>= 1.0.9)
  eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
  rack (>= 1.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
  atomic
tilt (1.4.1)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
virtus (1.0.0)
  axiom-types (~> 0.0.5)
  coercible (~> 0.2)
  descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
  equalizer (~> 0.0.7)
waitforit (0.0.1)
wasabi (3.1.0)
  httpi (~> 2.0)
  nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.4)
  selenium-webdriver (>= 2.18.0)
websocket (1.0.7)

PLATFORMS
 ruby

DEPENDENCIES
childprocess
cucumber (= 1.2.5)
grape (= 0.6.0)
haml
hashie
httparty
idp-clients (~> 0.1.8)
idp-content_service_mock
idp-user_service_mocks
idp-utilities
mirage (= 3.0.0.alpha.15)
newrelic_rpm (~> 3.6.8.168)
page_object
rack-fiber_pool
rack-test
rake
rspec
shotgun
simplecov
sinatra
sinatra-contrib
sinatra-reloader
thin
waitforit
watir-webdriver
```

My Stackato.yml is

```
name: weblogin
instances: 1
framework:
 type: rack
  mem: 128
 env:
  RACK_ENV: preprod
```

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile`?

Comment: hi let u check my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock i tried with adding bundler in my Gemfile but it doesn't work

Comment: Hey @santosh, can you please post your stackato.yml file, along with what version of the stackato micro cloud you're using?

Comment: check my stackato.yml